# Finding highest pair of dice in list

Tags: python, loops, sum, dice

I am writing a simple Yatzy app using Python, and I am a bit stuck on finding the best pair of dice. Here is the outline of the function:

```
Input: list containing five dice.
Output: highest sum of two dice with the same number. If no pairs found, then -1.
```

What would be the optimal way to write this function using Python? How can I scale it up for say two pairs or full house?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `scale it up for say two pairs or full house`, you can't just scale it up, it would imply a  different solution

Comment: @yatu Alright, thanks for that input. I would still love an answer to my problem though :)

Comment: I don't see any reason to "optimize" your code. Your priority should be writing understandable code, so that you or someone else can modify or expand the existing code in a few months time. This means that you will probably want to write some auxiliary methods that check for full house, multiple pairs etc. in descending order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a Python3 solution that uses the collections module.

```
from collections import Counter
from random import randint
roll = [randint(1, 6) for x in range(5)]

result = max([x for x, cnt in Counter(roll).items() if cnt==2] or [-1])

print(roll, '->', result)
```

By the way, there's an edge case in here (4 of a kinds = 2 pairs), depending on your required result you may want to compare like `cnt > 1` instead.